# Why does this simple assignment of a bool generate an error

Tags: c#, asp.net, console-application

Ok, I have this code - (console app), but it fails for winforms, asp.net, or whatever.

```
        DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
        rstData.Columns.Add("VisitDate", typeof(DateTime));
        DataRow OneRow = rstData.NewRow();
        OneRow["VisitDate"] = DBNull.Value;
        rstData.Rows.Add(OneRow);

        DateTime? dtTest = (DateTime?)rstData.Rows[0]["VisitDate"] as DateTime?;

        bool testbvalue = true;

        Console.WriteLine(testbvalue.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Hit enter to continue");

        Console.ReadLine();
```

when I run the above, I get this error:

[image]

No errors in the previous code is triggered, and yet the simple bool assignment fails.

If I comment out the first part of code, say like this:

```
        //DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
        //rstData.Columns.Add("VisitDate", typeof(DateTime));
        //DataRow OneRow = rstData.NewRow();
        //OneRow["VisitDate"] = DBNull.Value;
        //rstData.Rows.Add(OneRow);

        //DateTime? dtTest = (DateTime?)rstData.Rows[0]["VisitDate"] as DateTime?;

        bool testbvalue = true;

        Console.WriteLine(testbvalue.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Hit enter to continue");

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Then of course the code works.

Edit:
Stack trace shows this:

```
StackTrace  
"   at CSharpConsole.Program.Main(String[] args) in
C:\\Users\\Kalla\\source\\repos\\CSharpConsole\\Program.cs:line 20" string
```

so, stack trace does show the correct line - the debugger and VS highlights the wrong line.

Comment: What happens if you comment out everything from that line onwards instead of the first block of code? I suspect the issue is probably this: `(DateTime?)rstData.Rows[0]["VisitDate"]` where it's trying to do the cast before doing it using the subsequent `as`, but for whatever reason the debugger is showing the wrong info.

Comment: I doubt your boolean assignment has anything to do with this, and more likely the code above is what's erroring, and it's just showing the error on the wrong line for some reason. Please provide the full stack trace in your question (as text)

Comment: Don’t you use Release mode for debugging in VS?

Comment: @PetrNečas FWIW I've recreated the OPs issue in debug mode on a fresh project. Something really is confusing the debugger here - it's just reporting it as happening on the next line, no matter what that line is.

Comment: You can boil the issue [down to this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3xGy.png) - note the line number in the exception stack trace is correct, but the VS debugger is pausing on the line following.

Comment: yes, the debugger is showing on the wrong line - and it is reproducible here. I marked the answer below as an answer - I just have to watch out for what I consider a bit of a "choke" on VS's part to stop on the wrong line - been at this for some time, don't think I ever seen this.

Comment: @mason - I have included the stack trace. As me (and others here) have pointed out, vs simple highlights the wrong line of code. As noted this is unusual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bool assignment is fine.

The line above is producing the error i.e.

```
DateTime? dtTest = (DateTime?)rstData.Rows[0]["VisitDate"] as DateTime?;
```

For some reason, the debugger is pausing on the wrong line after the exception is thrown.

If you comment out the line with the bool assignment (and the related console output), you will see that the exception is reported on the `Console.WriteLine("Hit enter to continue")` line.

The direct cast (cast using brackets) on the `DateTime` assignment line is unnecessary and in fact the code runs fine if it is removed:

```
DateTime? dtTest = rstData.Rows[0]["VisitDate"] as DateTime?;
```

However, I'm still not sure why the debugger is pausing on the wrong line.

Comment: yes, indeed! And yes, the cast vs "as DateTime" works. (from what I can tell, that's not really a cast anymore, is it??? To be REALLY fair, using "as DateTime?" is the best answer, and MORE surprising that (DateTime2) as a cast does not work!!

Comment: Sorry I meant to say the direct cast, which is casting using brackets. Will update

Comment: The as operator does a test before casting an if its not of that type it will just assume it as null. And that it what happening here. A non existing value will not be null but a dummy Type of DBNull itself and you can't cast DBNull to DateTime. This DataTable/DataRow stuff is pretty old its predates nullable types. So actually the pattern should be to test explicitly for null `if (rstData.IsNull(0))`and then do the appropriate thing.

Comment: Gee, IsNull() for all those assignments? The better choice of course is to not cast, and use "As DateTime2" as pointed out by YungDeiza